# Omit 'do!' in computation expression

Tags: f#

Is it possible to put together a computation expression builder that can sequence two or more expressions without putting `do!` in front of each one?

If I've read the [relevant section of the manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597448) correctly, this should be possible through the builder's `Combine` method. However, my `Combine` method doesn't appear to be used; instead, I get a compiler warning suggesting that I use `ignore` to discard the result.

For instance, given an [F# State monad](http://fsharpcode.blogspot.com/2008/12/f-state-monad-type-state-state-state-of.html), I'd like to be able to do this:

```
let hello who = State (fun lines -> lines @ [sprintf "hello %s" who])
let m = state {
    hello "world"
    hello "F#"
}
let l = Execute m []
// l should now contain ["hello world"; "hello F#"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what Dario wrote, you cannot redefine the usual sequencing to behave as monadic `do!` (even if you decided not to support non-monadic operations in your computations). The problem is that usual sequencing isn't handled in any special way by the translator, so there is no interception point that you could use. Your example will be translated like this:

```
let m = state.Delay(fun () ->
  hello "world"
  hello "F#"
  state.Zero())
```

The call to `hello` is not wrapped into any member call that could be redefined.

In an **earlier version** of F# sequencing used to be translated to calls to `Let` member like this:

```
let m = state.Delay(fun () ->
  state.Let(hello "world", fun _ ->
    state.Let(hello "F#", fun _ -> 
      state.Zero())))
```

So it *was* possible to do what you wanted, but it cannot be done in the current version (I believe one reason was that this adds too much wrapping which hurts the performance).

Comment: Thanks - I must have been thinking of the way this worked in the earlier betas. In which case, what's the purpose of the `Combine` method? Its signature `(a : M<unit>, b : M<T>) -> M<T>` suggests that its purpose is _'do `a` then do `b`'_.

Answer (score 5):

No, because that's what regular `do` is for. If you want monadic do, i.e. `do!`, you have to be explicit. **Example:**

```
let m = state {
    printfn "World"
    hello "World"
    return 42
}
```

- The `printfn` expression is of type `unit`, and there is a `do printfn` implicit.
- And in the `hello` case? We'd need monadic binding!

Now how would the compiler know what to choose, `do` or `do!`? Maybe by types (Scala does this), but right now, it doesn't. So it just assumes a regular `do` anywhere.